# unable to get categories value from table property using foreign key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router-dom

I want to get the detail property per id from clicking the property list, I have got the `property` value but can't retrieve the `category` values ​​using the foreign key.

This is my `test.jsx` component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { axiosInstance } from '../config/config.js';

function PropertyList() {
  const [properties, setProperties] = useState([]);

  const fetchPro = async () => {
    await axiosInstance.get('/propertys').then((res) => {
      // console.log(res.data.result);
      const datas = res.data.result;

      setProperties(datas);
      console.log(datas);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPro();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Property List</h1>
      <ul>
        {properties.map((property) => (
          <div className="bg-danger">
            <li key={property.id}>
              <a href={`/propertydetaillist/${property.id}`}>{property.name}</a>
            </li>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PropertyList;
```

This is my `testdetail.jsx` component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { axiosInstance } from '../config/config.js';
import { useParams, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function PropertyDetails(props) {
  const [property, setProperty] = useState({});

  const { id } = useParams();
  const fetchProDetail = async () => {
    await axiosInstance.get(`/propertys/detail/${id}`).then((res) => {
      // console.log(res.data.result);
      const datas = res.data.result;

      setProperty(datas);
      console.log(datas);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProDetail();
    console.log(property);
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div>
      {property ? (
        <div>
          <h1>{property.category.id}</h1>
          <h1>{property.name}</h1>
          <p>{property.description}</p>
          <p>Price: {property.propertyImage}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default PropertyDetails;
```

This is the problem when I click one of the property list
[image]

I want to get the categories value by using foreign key in properties table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`property` is initially an object:

```js
const [property, setProperty] = useState({});
```

The code only checks that `property` exists, but not that `property.category` exists prior to accessing an `id` property.

```
<div>
  {property ? (
    <div>
      <h1>{property.category.id}</h1> // error when property.category undefined
      <h1>{property.name}</h1>
      <p>{property.description}</p>
      <p>Price: {property.propertyImage}</p>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <p>Loading...</p>
  )}
</div>
```

Just place a null-check on the `category` property. Provide a fallback value if you like. `{}` is a defined, truthy object, so if you are also wanting to render the loading UI while the `property` data is fetched then I suggest also starting with a falsey `property` value.

Example:

```
const [property, setProperty] = useState(null);

...

<div>
  {property ? (
    <div>
      <h1>{property.category?.id ?? "No Category Id"}</h1>
      <h1>{property.name}</h1>
      <p>{property.description}</p>
      <p>Price: {property.propertyImage}</p>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <p>Loading...</p>
  )}
</div>
```